# Python: New Object uses attribute from previous Object

Tags: python, python-3.x, binding, scope

I am creating three `Game` objects. However, the second and third object are not initializing new `blocks` lists. When I am debugging, I can see that they use the list from the initial Game object and just append blocks. What is the reason for this? And how can I have objects not using the same `blocks` list?

```
class Game(object):

    blocks = []

    def __init__(self):
        cords = [
            [0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3],
            [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3],
            [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3],
            [3, 0], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3]
        ]

        random.shuffle(cords)

        for i in range(0, 16):
            self.blocks.append(Block(i + 1, cords[i][0], cords[i][1]))
```

Comment: Stop binding the object to the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of how you are defining `blocks` - as a *class attribute*. A class attribute does not belong to any single instance of a class, and is shared everywhere on the class-level to which it is binded.

To have each `Game` object have its own `blocks`, you want `blocks` to be an *instance attribute*. You can bind blocks to each instance of a class in the `__init__` method, such that every `Game` has its own list `blocks`.

```
def __init__(self):
    self.blocks = []
```